# Problema clonando objeto en java: al modificar el objeto origen, se modifica la copia también

Tags: java, clone

Estoy ciertamente confuso a la hora de intentar clonar un objeto.

Por un lado e intentado utilizar la interfaz `Cloneable`

```
@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Consultas consultas=new Consultas();

    consultas.id = id;
    consultas.idOrg = idOrg;
    consultas.idUsu = idUsu;
    consultas.consulta = consulta;
    consultas.estado = estado;
    consultas.fecha = fecha;
    consultas.leidoAnt = leidoAnt;
    consultas.idPerfil = idPerfil;
    consultas.fechaUltima = fechaUltima;
    consultas.idTema = idTema;
    consultas.ficheroAdjunto = ficheroAdjunto;
    consultas.leidoConc = leidoConc;
    consultas.marca = marca;
    consultas.solicitadoTeamviewer=solicitadoTeamviewer;

    return consultas;
}

public Object clonar(){
    try {
        return this.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Pues bien, esto no me sirve, pues aunque me copia bien el objeto, cuando intento modificar algún campo, me lo modifica en ambos objetos, la copia y el copiado, por lo cual entiendo que con `clone()` también se copia la referencia en memoria.

Pues bien, viendo que eso no funciona, me he aventurado a a crear un pequeño método para clonar objetos.

```
public static Object clonar(Object acopiar)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Class<?> clazz;
        Object obj=null;
        try {
            clazz = Class.forName(acopiar.getClass().getName());
            obj=clazz.newInstance();
            Map<String,Method> mapa=new HashMap<String,Method>();
            Method[] metodos=clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
            for(Method method2:metodos){
                mapa.put(method2.getName(), method2);
            }

            for(Method method:metodos){

                if(method.getName().startsWith("get")){
                    try{
                        Method setter;
                        String nombre=method.getName();
                        Object value=method.invoke(acopiar);
                        setter = obj.getClass().getMethod(nombre.replace("get","set"),mapa.get(nombre.replace("get","set")).getParameterTypes());
                        setter.invoke(obj, value);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("No se ha podido settear el campo: "+method.getName()+" : "+e.getClass()+" --> "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e1) {
            System.out.println("Exception:  "+e1.getClass()+" --> "+e1.getMessage());
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Pues bien, incluso con este método, que me crea bien el objeto con todas sus propiedades, cuando modifico el objeto origen, se me modifica la copia también!

```
Consultas aux=itConsultas.next();
                        Consultas copia=(Consultas)Utilidades.clonar(aux);
                        aux.getId().setIdConsulta(Integer.parseInt(idsSplited[0]));
                        aux.getId().setIdRespuesta(++lastValue);
                        copias.add(copia);
```

Aquí es donde intento copiar un objeto.

Si alguien me dijera que puedo estar haciendo mal, o que se me escapa se lo agradecería.

**EDIT:** He probado a crear un constructor-copia el cual no me funciona, me siguen compartiendo instancia, he sobreescrito ademas el metodo `clone`
 segun me ha dicho @Fernando y siguen compartiendo instancia(Aunque como dijo Luiggi esto no servia). Alguna sugerencia mas? La verdad que ya no se que mas puede ser...

Aqui el codigo del constructor-copia a ver si se me paso algo

```
public Consultas(Consultas a_copiar) {

        this.id = a_copiar.id;
        this.idOrg = a_copiar.idOrg;
        this.idUsu = a_copiar.idUsu;
        this.consulta = a_copiar.consulta;
        this.estado = a_copiar.estado;
        this.fecha = a_copiar.fecha;
        this.leidoAnt = a_copiar.leidoAnt;
        this.idPerfil = a_copiar.idPerfil;
        this.fechaUltima = a_copiar.fechaUltima;
        this.idTema = a_copiar.idTema;
        this.ficheroAdjunto = a_copiar.ficheroAdjunto;
        this.leidoConc = a_copiar.leidoConc;
        this.marca = a_copiar.marca;
        this.solicitadoTeamviewer=a_copiar.solicitadoTeamviewer;


        }
```

Comment: Tal vez pueda ser de ayuda echar un vistazo en el "Item 11: Override clone judiciously" del libro *Effective Java™ Second Edition* por Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 2):

El método `super.clone` basado en `Object#clone` devuelve lo que se conoce como una copia superficial (shallow copy). El código que has implementado usando reflection también devuelve una copia superficial donde solo copias el estado de un objeto a otro, y eso que solo copias el estado de los getters y setters declarado en esa clase, no estás evaluando los de los métodos padre y algún campo que no posea estos métodos (podría decir que el método que has implementado tiene uso para clases simples). Es por eso que cuando copias un objeto, al copiar los datos primitivos no hay problema, pero al copiar una referencia (es decir, un objeto) copias la referencia tal cual y al modificar el estado en un objeto se ve "reflejado" en el otro.

Lo que buscas se llama copia profunda (deep copy). Para ello, existen varias opciones:

- Si tienes pocas clases, te recomiendo crearles un constructor-copia. Es decir, que reciban una instancia de sí mismos y permitan "copiar" todas las propiedades.
- Si tienes demasiadas clases o tienes clases muy complejas (muchos atributos, entre ellos referencias o colecciones que almacenan referencias), otra estrategia es que tus clases a clonar y todas las clases declaradas dentro implementen la interfaz `Serializable`, de manera que solo serializas y deserializas el objeto. El objeto deserializado ya es una copia totalmente nueva. Ojo que este método tiene un precio y es el impacto en memoria: si tu objeto a clonar es muy pesado en memoria, al serializarlo puede que ocupes demasiado espacio y en tu aplicación salte un OOM.
- Usar alguna librería de copiado a profundidad como [Java Deep Cloning](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning/) que usa reflection o [`SerializationUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) que usa serialización/deserialización en memoria.
- Basado en el caso de serialización/deserialización, en lugar de usar `Serializable` y la serialización de Java, serializar la información a un formato textual como JSON, XML, YAML u otro, y usar una librería como Jackson para la serialización/deserialización de la información. El objeto deserializado ya es una copia totalmente nueva de la información que buscas.

Más información:

- [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/1065197) (sería bueno traducirlo aquí en el sitio)

Comment: Hola Luiggi, muchas gracais por tu aporte, tirare por crear un constructor copia ya que solo lo necesito en una clase concreta. Aun asi no entiendo porque mi metodo no sirve, si al final me creo una nueva instancia, debería ser otro objeto nuevo con su nueva referencia en memoria. Pero bueno, igualmetne gracias por todo

Answer (score 1):

tu primera aproximación era correcta (implementar la interface Clonable) pero la implementación no. No puedes hacer `return super.clone();` porque precisamente tiene el comportamiento estándar que es el que no quieres. Para conseguirlo tienes que crear un objeto y asignarle las propiedades. Te dejo un ejemplo para que veas como se haría (aunque hay variantes, como la que has usado con reflection):

Clase a clonar:

```
public class TestClonarMyClass implements Cloneable {

    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;

    public String getProp1() {
        return prop1;
    }
    public void setProp1(String prop1) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }
    public String getProp2() {
        return prop2;
    }
    public void setProp2(String prop2) {
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass [prop1=" + prop1 + ", prop2=" + prop2 + "]";
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        final TestClonarMyClass newObj = new TestClonarMyClass();

        newObj.setProp1(prop1);
        newObj.setProp2(prop2);

        return newObj;
    }

}
```

Código de ejemplo:

```
public class TestClonar {   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        final TestClonarMyClass obj1 = new TestClonarMyClass();
        obj1.setProp1("prop1");
        obj1.setProp2("prop2");

        final TestClonarMyClass obj2 = (TestClonarMyClass) obj1.clone();
        obj2.setProp1("prop1-b");
        obj2.setProp2("prop2-b");

        System.out.println("OBJ1" + obj1);
        System.out.println("\nOBJ2" + obj2);
    }
}
```

Verás que la salida del ejemplo es esta:

```
OBJ1MyClass [prop1=prop1, prop2=prop2]

OBJ2MyClass [prop1=prop1-b, prop2=prop2-b]
```

Como verás los valores de las propiedades son distintas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, por lo que veo consistiría el pasar un objeto y crear una nueva instancia y ir asociandole los parámetros. Ya pense en dicha solucion, pero me parecía poco re utilizable y tedioso(ya que el objeto tiene muchos atributos) decidí decantarme por mi código de reflection. Ahora que se que de esa manera es posible, me gustaría saber que es lo que falla en mi método, ¿como es posible que devuelva la misma referencia del objeto a copiar?

Comment: No lo he llegado a probar tu código y no te puedo decir, pero la manera correcta de hacerlo es como te digo. En cuanto a reutilizarlo siempre puedes usar reflection para recorrer las propiedades del objeto y asignarlas al nuevo. La clave es que para que la función de clonar funcione siempre tienes que crear un nuevo objeto y luego asignarle las propiedades del objeto actual. Después devuelves el objeto nuevo, y listo!!!

Comment: Si claro, al final es la parte fundamental, instanciar un nuevo objeto y retornar ese. La cosa es que en las primeras lineas de mi método me declaro una nueva instancia y con reflection le voy asignando los valores y luego devuelvo esa nueva instancia. Por eso no entiendo como me modifica ambos objetos O.O. De todas formas muchas gracias por tus aportaciones @Fernando Forcén

Comment: Este ejemplo sigue mostrando la copia superficial (shallow copy) y no la copia a profundidad (deep copy).

Comment: Hola Luiggi, porque dices que es una copia superficial?

Comment: [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/1065197)

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso, es una muy buena pregunta para traducir aquí en el sitio.

Comment: Hola fernando, se la voy a dar a luiggi por la explicacion y las diversas opciones, igualmente muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: No hay problema, lo importante es que hayas conseguido ayuda.